# Projection to select elements from List<T>

Tags: c#, generics, projection

I have a class

```
public class MyClass
{
  public p1 {get; set}
  public p2 {get;set;}
  public p3 {get;set;}
}
```

and a generic list `List<MyClass> myList`.

I know that I can write

```
var myvar = from x in myList select new {x.p1, x.p2};
```

How do I write a projection to select only p1 and p2 from MyList using extension Select method?

```
myList.Select(????
```

Documentation [Enumerable.Select](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548891(v=vs.110).aspx) only shows how to select single value

```
IEnumerable<int> squares =
    Enumerable.Range(1, 10).Select(x => x * x);
```

Comment: if it helps, Resharper can switch LINQ method syntax to query syntax and vice versa

Comment: Edited question to add research presumably done by OP. Unfortunately it did not seem to make question much better... oh well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pretty straightforward

```
myList.Select(elem => new { elem.p1, elem.p2 });
```